# Xcode, My app icon gets the gloss effect but my app store 512 icon doesnt?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I'm not sure where to set this.

But my gloss effect is added to my app icon which is shown on the iPhone, as I have "Icon already includes gloss effects" set to No in my plist file, but my bigger 512 x 512 icon files used in the app store doesn't have the gloss effect/

How do I set this ?

Comment: Sorry I meant 512, have edited question.

Comment: Are you uploading the 512x512 icon as PNG? I've seen this before on the iPhondeDevSDK forum: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22931-how-get-no-gloss-icon-app-store.html They solved it by using a JPG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to give shine effect of app icons, you have to set `UIPrerenderedIcon` key to your application’s Info.plist file.